# Need to update a column based on ORDER BY clause : Error 1093 Can't specify target table for update in FROM clause

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to update an ix column in my table based on an ORDER BY clause.

I intend to run this after inserts and updates on a very large table so to improve performance when SELECT is executed later.

```
UPDATE 1_products set ix = (
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
            ORDER BY product_group.branch_added, product_group.position , make , model
        )
    FROM (
        1_products p
        LEFT JOIN 1_product_group product_group ON product_group.id = p.fk_group_id
    ) 
    WHERE p.sn > 0
    ORDER BY product_group.branch_added , product_group.position , make , model
);
```

I found this as a solution

```
DROP TABLE ixu;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ixu(id INT, ix int)ENGINE=MEMORY;

INSERT INTO ixu(id,ix)
SELECT p.id,row_number() over( ORDER BY product_group.branch_added , product_group.position , make , model)
FROM
    1_products p
        LEFT JOIN
    1_product_group product_group ON product_group.id = p.fk_group_id
WHERE
    p.sn > 0
ORDER BY product_group.branch_added , product_group.position , make , model;

UPDATE 1_products
        INNER JOIN
    ixu ON 1_products.id = ixu.id 
SET 
    1_products.ix = ixu.ix;

SELECT 
    *
FROM
    1_products
ORDER BY ix;
```

Comment: Which error are you getting? Please edit your question to include the entire error message.

Comment: Are you aware of partitioning?

Comment: will take a look at partitioning now. Was also thinking of selecting to a temp table then performing an update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it without the use of a temp table:

```
UPDATE 1_products p
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT p.id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY g.branch_added, g.position, make, model) ix
  FROM 1_products p LEFT JOIN 1_product_group g 
  ON g.id = p.fk_group_id
  WHERE p.sn > 0
) t ON p.id = t.id
SET p.ix = t.ix
```